# Delete temporary files on startup

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos

I have a program which when it runs it fills Temp folder with lots of .tmp files. This is causing C drive to fill up. I have been asked to investigate if it's possible to write a script in dos to delete temporary files on startup. I also wish to delay the program starting until all files are deleted. This would need to happen every time on start-up. It would be great if this could be installed via a flash drive. 
I would be grateful on any pointers on how this could be done

Answer (score 3):

The little batch I am using to delete my temporary files:

```
@echo off
rd %temp% /s /q
md %temp%
cls
echo Temporary Files have been deleted!
echo.
pause
```

%temp% is a path which always results in your current temporary folder. However note that there are more temporary file locations like C:\Windows\temp.
If you just want to delete TMP files, go with `del C:\<MyPath>\*.tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more sophisticated ways, but the good old fashioned `del c:\Temp\*.*` should be a good start.

There's a list of all the options, here: http://www.computerhope.com/delhlp.htm
You will probably want /F (delete read only), /S (sub-directories) and /Q (quiet)

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the following row in c:\autoexec.bat file may help:

```
del c:\path\to\temp\files\*.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for replies. This is what I'm using

```
c:
cd \
cd "c:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temp\"
del *.tmp /f/s/q
echo All tmp files deleted.
pause
```

This seems to do what I want it to do. Now I need it to do this everytime PC starts up. Is there a way to install this via flash drive? ie write a batch file with all commands, put on flash drive. double click .bat file, now installed and will run on startup? (Have a number of PCs which need same thing)

Comment: Add it to the `autoexec.bat` as @Kel suggests (if your PC has one) BTW the first 4 lines can be simplified into `del "c:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temp\*.tmp /f/s/q"` (no need for the drive and directory changing)